# LINQ Getting Distinct Data and looping through to get related data

Tags: c#, linq, loops, distinct

I'm new to Linq. I want to know whether this is the best way or are there any other ways to do this.

I have a requirement where from a web service, I receive a list of items:

```
class Item {

  string ItemName { get; set;} 
  string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

I receive the following data:

```
ItemName: Item1; GroupName: A
ItemName: Item2; GroupName: B
ItemName: Item3; GroupName: B
ItemName: Item4; GroupName: A
ItemName: Item5; GroupName: A
```

Now I want to get all of the unique Groups in the list, and associate all the Items to that Group. So I made a class:

```
class Group {
   string GroupName { get; set; }
   List<string> Items { get; set; }
}
```

So that there is a single group and all associated Items will be under the List.

I made two LINQ statements:

```
var uniqueGroups = (from g in webservice
        where g.Group != null
        select g.GroupName).Distinct();
```

Then I loop through it

```
foreach (var gn in uniqueGroups)
{
   var itemsAssociated = (from item in webservice 
                          where item.GroupName = gn.ToString()
                          select new {
                               });
}
```

and then I got the items, and save them to my object.

Is this the best way to do this or are there any LINQ statement that can do all these in one go?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it might be clearer if you said what the data type of the output is, I mean - what do you want out of this?  A `Dictionary<string, List<Item>>` perhaps?... or?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
//List<Item> webservice = list with items from your webservice
var result = (from i in items
              group i by i.GroupName into groups
              select new Group()
              {
                  GroupName = groups.Key,
                  Items = groups.Select(g => g.ItemName).ToList()
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: This is perfect. Now I know how to group in Linq. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you want [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx)

```
var itemsByGroup = items.GroupBy(i => i.GroupName);

foreach (var group in itemsByGroup)
{
    var groupName = group.Key;
    var itemsForThisGroup = group;

    foreach (var item in itemsForThisGroup)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine(item.ItemName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That could be done all at once with an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) and [`Enumerable.GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx):

```
var groupItems =
    webservice.Where(i => i.GroupName != null)
              .GroupBy(i => i.GroupName)
              .Select(grp => new { Group = grp.Key, Items = grp.ToList() });
foreach (var groupItem in groupItems)
    Console.WriteLine("Groupname: {0} Items: {1}"
        , groupItem.Group
        , string.Join(",", groupItem.Items.Select(i => i.ItemName)));
```

Distinct is useless since `GroupBy` will always make the groups distinct, that's the nature of a group.

Here's running code: http://ideone.com/R3jjZ

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
 webservice.ToLookup(k => k.GroupName);
```

That would eliminate the need for the extra class.

Hope this helps!